# Convert year and day of year into pandas timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to convert a string containing year and day of year into pandas timestamp?

e.g.

```
a_str = '2000120'  # year 2000, day 120
```

I tried:

```
pd.Timestamp(year=a_str[:4], dayofyear=a_str[4:])
```

but I get this error

```
*** TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dayofyear'
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`%j`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) which is the day of the year:

```
In [11]: dt.datetime.strptime("2000120", "%Y%j")
Out[11]: datetime.datetime(2000, 4, 29, 0, 0)

In [12]: pd.to_datetime("2000120", format="%Y%j")
Out[12]: Timestamp('2000-04-29 00:00:00')
```

Note: Whilst the docs say:

> Day of the year as a zero-padded decimal number.

This doesn't apear to be the case (it works even if it's not zero padded):

```
In [13]: dt.datetime.strptime("200020", "%Y%j")
Out[13]: datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 20, 0, 0)

In [14]: pd.to_datetime("200020", format="%Y%j")
Out[14]: Timestamp('2000-01-20 00:00:00')
```

---

*I don't think you can use the Timestamp constructor here, you have to use the `to_datetime` method (which allows you to pass `format`).*